# Way to convert claims tokens to Kerberos that SP2010 accepts

Tags: networking, f5-big-ip

I'm hoping there is an F5 way to do what is described in this article:

http://blog.auth360.net/2010/12/03/the-triumvirate-uag-2010sp1-ad-fs-2-0-and-kerberos/

Users login to a mobile app using claims-based authentication at the front-end and need to connect to SharePoint 2010 using Kerberos at the back-end. SharePoint 2010 in this case does NOT support claims. A user will logon via AD FS and then need F5 to request a Kerberos ticket on behalf of the user and use that ticket to authenticate to SharePoint 2010. We’re mixing authentication using claims-based authentication at the edge and then Kerberos for authenticating to SharePoint 2010.

Update:
I know SharePoint 2010 can support claims. In this case I am not allowed to modify the existing SharePoint 2010 environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Claims to Windows Token Service](http://www.theidentityguy.com/articles/2010/10/15/access-owa-with-adfs.html) available with AD FS 2 to take a claims principal issued by AD FS and turn it into a constrained Kerberos ticket.

That being said, SharePoint 2010 [definitely supports native Claims authentication](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/05/27/understanding-sharepoint-2010-claims-authentication.aspx) used with the client object model.  It is not easy, [but it is possible](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/06/04/using-the-client-object-model-with-a-claims-based-auth-site-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx).

Further, if you have a SharePoint add-in which is what is really requiring use of Kerberos, SharePoint will automatically use C2WTS.

Comment: I know SharePoint can support claims. In this case I am not allowed to modify SharePoint. Updated my question with this. I will look into C2WTS. Thanks!